# Mostrar solo numero enteros sin decimales despues del punto

Tags: php, html

```html
<div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><?php echo($valorObtenido*100)/$valorMax; ?>%</div>
```

Quiero que solo muestre porcentaje entero por ejemplo 30%, 50% no con decimales como 33.3333%, hay una funcon que haga eso, seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres eliminar los decimales solo usa:

`echo number_format( ($valorObtenido*100)/$valorMax, 0 );` resultado: 33%

Si quieres dejar 2 decimales:

`echo number_format( ($valorObtenido*100)/$valorMax, 2 );` resultado: 33.33%

Si quieres redondear hacia arriba:

`echo ceil( ($valorObtenido*100)/$valorMax );` resultado: 34%

Si quieres redondear hacia abajo:

`echo foor( ($valorObtenido*100)/$valorMax );` resultado: 33%

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar [`round`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php), [`ceil`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ceil.php) o [`floor`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floor.php) (*dependiendo de como necesites que sea redondeado el número*)

#### Ejemplo

```
<div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">
  <?php echo round($valorObtenido * 100 / $valorMax); ?>%
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el round. Para tu caso seria algo parecido a esto:

```
<div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"><?php echo round(($valorObtenido*100)/$valorMax,0); ?>%</div>
```

Para mas información te dejo la documentación:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php

Espero que te pueda ayudar! Un saludo :)